# Zerobrane: Unable to right-click items in Project Tree on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: zerobrane

Zerobrane Studio Version: 1.90
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
CPU: Intel i5-4590 (4) @ 3.700GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
Memory: 2565MiB / 7852MiB

Video: https://app.box.com/s/dui1kxuat8saodg8hr9ws9qz91ewgop8

As title suggests. I never had this issue while working on windows. Sometimes right-clicking works, albeit very rarely. It seems the project tree is not able to properly capture my cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a known issue that has been fixed in the master branch (see the discussion in ticket [#1062](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/1062)), so you may want to use that or apply the fix from the ticket.